# Get Images in a column of Jqgrid based on id value in another column of the grid

Tags: jqgrid, get, rowid, identify

I have a JQGrid with 4 columns as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            jQuery("#toolbar").jqGrid({
                url:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/TestServlet?q=1&action=fetchData',
                datatype: "xml",
                mtype: 'POST',
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%',
                colNames:['LocationImage','City','State','LocationID'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'LocationImage',index:'LocationImage',align: 'center', formatter: imageFormatter},
                    {name:'City',index:'City', width:200,fixed:true,sortable:true,align:'center',editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false,size:500}},
                    {name:'State',index:'State', width:200,fixed:true,sortable:true,align:'center',editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false,size:50}},
                    {name:'LocationID',index:'LocationID',width:60,align:'center',hidden:true,editable:false, editoptions:{readonly:true,size:30}
                ],
                paging: true,
                rowNum:16,
                rowTotal:2000,
                rownumbers: true,
                rownumWidth: 25,
                rowList:[16,32,48],
                viewrecords: true,
                loadonce: true,
                gridview: true,
                pager: $("#ptoolbar"),
                sortname: 'Name',
                sortorder: "asc",
                caption: "Test Grid"
            })
            jQuery("#toolbar").jqGrid('navGrid','#ptoolbar',{del:false,add:false,edit:false});
            jQuery("#toolbar").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
        });
        function imageFormatter(el, cval, opts) {
    var num = '2';
            return ("<center><img src='../gd/images/" + num+".png' height='180px' width='180px' /></center>")
        }
```

Here I have hardcoded num as '2' and so displaying 2.png in the first column i.e. LocationImage, what i need is that the value for num should be from the 4th column i.e. LocationID (note its a hidden column).

Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks,
Deepna

Comment: how to accept a reply ? i can just see options of feedback

Comment: somehow being in UI i think - this website is not that ui friendly..:)

Comment: if you find answers good then click on tick to mark it answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `imageFormatter` function to be like this:

```
function imageFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){     
  var num = $("#" + options.rowId).find("td[aria-describedby='toolbar_LocationID']").text();                
  return "<center><img src='../gd/images/" + num + ".png' height='180px' width='180px' /></center>";
}
```

Comment: David - I tried this code but the num returned null - its not picking the value from the LocationID column.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I'm not rally sure about it, I can't test now. but here's what you can do

From the options parameter you can get the row id, check [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) and then you can get Location Id with that row Id using getCell or getGridParam. and you can use this value for setting the image.

If this doesn't work for custom formatter, you can use setCol method in gridComplete property of JqGrid.

Now this is going to work for only one id. If you want to set image for all rows, get row ids using getDataIDs method in a variable and t hen go with for loop and use setCol.

I Hope this helps

Comment: Piyush - thanks for pointing me to the Formatter link, however i got another way to fix this issue... will explain that as an answer post

Comment: perhaps you could link to that post??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue in the below way

1. Changed the first column in the Grid to Location ID
2. Now in the formatter - when I say "cellvalue", it actually
   returns the location id
3. This location id is then set into the variable num (i.e. num =
   cellvalue)
4. Now the formatter code replaces the id value with an image based
   on id.png

Thanks,
Deepna